# Создать 3-D array

Tags: python, numpy

Хочу написать SGD для расчета SVM_loss в векторной реализации (если это возможно). Функция потерь hinge loss.

Есть матрица **X[idx]** (100х3000) - 100 объектов, 3000 фич. Есть матрица **W** (3000,10 - после транспонирования) - 10 классов. Есть матрица **mask** (10х3000), в ней значения 0 - если скор по функции потерь 0 или меньше; и 1, если больше. 
**dW** - градиент.

Хочу написать следующее:

- берем первый объект мини-батча (1, 3000) делаем outer product с np.ones(10), то есть получаем (10, 3000)
- берем первый столбец из mask (10,100), перемножаем с (10, 3000) из предыдущего пункта. Тогда те классы, по которым у нас лосс 0 и градиент не нужен, значения будут 0, на тех весах, где есть ошибка и нужен градиент, значения будут.
- вычитаем то, что получилось в предыдущем пункте из dW (10,3000)

Но это для одного объекта, а хочется создать 3-D array (10,3000,100), тогда каждый слой в глубину ( , , n) умножался на столбец n из mask и полученная 2-D array вычитается из dW. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне задать эту логику (и можно ли в векторной реализации, чтобы без цикла)? Пробовал reshape и vsplit, не могу задать нужную форму для 3-D array

Пример X (3 объекта, 4 признака), W (2 класса, 4 признака), y (3 объекта, 2 класса):

```
X = array([[ 1.95325352,  2.36870698,  1.48356686,  1.73907457],
       [ 1.27666329,  0.72126126, -0.30994913, -0.46203272],
       [ 0.06247519, -0.98329737, -0.39707169, -1.7027278 ]])
W = array([[ 0.0005306 ,  0.00064946,  0.00030296,  0.00016182],
       [ 0.0002176 ,  0.00219748,  0.00044518, -0.00029858]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 0])
dW = array([[ 0.        ,  4.07326561,  1.57068942,  2.97976966],
       [ 0.        , -4.07326561, -1.57068942, -2.97976966]])
```

Если возможно, то нужно получить градиент dW (2 класса, 4 признака) в векторной реализации

```
def svm_loss(W, X, y, reg):
    dW = np.zeros(np.shape(W))
    loss_total = 0
    k = 0
    while k < 100:
        idx = np.random.randint(X.shape[0], size = 100)
        scores = np.dot(X[idx], np.transpose(W))
        num_classes = np.shape(np.transpose(W))[1]
        y_score = scores[idx, y[idx]] 
        margins = scores - y_score + 1
        margins[idx, y] = 0
        margins_loss = np.maximum(0, margins) + reg * np.sum(np.power(W, 2))
        loss = np.sum(margins_loss)
        mask = ma.masked_greater(margins, 0).data*1

        k += 1

    return loss, dW
```

Comment: Под результатом вы имеете ввиду посчитанный градиент на указанных примерах, или достаточно просто указать, что необходимо рассчитать градиент?

Comment: желательно посчитанный, чтобы можно было сравнить результаты...

Comment: Кстати а почему не хотите воспользоваться [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html)?

Comment: Хочу расписать, чтобы понять, как работает под капотом. Я уже написал свой вариант lossa, но с циклами для расчета градиента. Вот просто интересно, можно ли без циклов

Comment: Так может тогда попробовать разобраться в реализации  SGDClassifier?

Comment: Да, не знал, что там можно код смотреть. Спасибо